# Probability of satisfying an event if I only have 3 attempts to do so

Tags: probability, statistics

For example, if I want to attempt to win a challenge, and I only have three tries to win the challenge, then what would $P$(I win the challenge) be if the probability of me winning the challenge in 1 attempt is $\frac{1}{3}$? The attempts are independent, and if I win the challenge on an attempt or fail all 3 tries, then I will not attempt the challenge anymore.

To try and solve this question, I did the following:
$P$(Lose an attempt) = 1 - $\frac{1}{3}$ = $\frac{2}{3}$

$P$(Win all 3 attempts) = 1 - $(\frac{2}{3})^3$

But I don't know if this is correct, since I would stop making further attempts if I won on the first try, or on the second try, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that is always helpful for these little cases is to enumerate all possibilities. To this end, let $W$ represent a win and $L$ represent a loss. If we have a $W$, then the sequence stops:

$$W,LW,LLW,LLL$$

Then

$$P(\text{Win any attempt})=P(W,LW,LLW)=P(W)+P(LW)+P(LLW)$$

$$=\frac{1}{3}+\frac{2}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^2\cdot\frac{1}{3}=\frac{19}{27}$$

Alternatively,

$$P(\text{Win any attempt})=1-P(LLL)=1-\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^3=\frac{19}{27}$$

The trick for this approach is noticing that not winning at all implies you have lost all three attempts. Thus, the probability of winning is simply $1$ minus the probability of losing $3$ times in a row.